# what is the use of currency symbols in Money DataType of Tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I was referring MSDN about `MONEY` datatype in TSQL, I found a list of currency symbols.

Can any one specify the use of those symbols relating to TSQL query

```
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms179882.aspx
```

Comment: And what is your query?

Comment: question makes no sense as it stands

Comment: How to use those symbols and their hexa decimal representations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of these symbols affects how constants are interpreted `SELECT £1.00` is a literal of the money datatype. Without the prefix it would be treated as decimal/numeric.

---

```
SELECT sql_variant_property($1.00,'basetype') AS basetype,
       sql_variant_property($1.00,'precision') AS precision, 
       sql_variant_property($1.00,'scale') AS scale, 
       sql_variant_property($1.00,'maxlength') AS maxlength

+----------+-----------+-------+-----------+
| basetype | precision | scale | maxlength |
+----------+-----------+-------+-----------+
| money    |        19 |     4 |         8 |
+----------+-----------+-------+-----------+
```

---

```
SELECT sql_variant_property(1.00,'basetype') AS basetype,
       sql_variant_property(1.00,'precision') AS precision, 
       sql_variant_property(1.00,'scale') AS scale, 
       sql_variant_property(1.00,'maxlength') AS maxlength

+----------+-----------+-------+-----------+
| basetype | precision | scale | maxlength |
+----------+-----------+-------+-----------+
| numeric  |         3 |     2 |         5 |
+----------+-----------+-------+-----------+
```

It makes no difference which one you use.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN $1.00 = £1.00
           THEN 'Equal'
         ELSE 'Not Equal'
       END /*Returns Equal*/
```

These are optional prefixes in strings cast to money. It makes no difference if they are there or not.

Comment: can we display the currency symbols in result table with out using cast as varchar and then concat with symbol

Comment: @N.Dinesh.Reddy no. Though this is best done by your application anyway.